# Second Largest Number (of 3/4 numbers) using Ternary Operator in C?

Tags: c, numbers, ternary-operator

All the examples online for ternary operators just have the method to find the largest number.

Is it possible to devise a code to find the second largest number of 3 or 4 numbers using ternary operators?

Comment: You don't have to make excuses for asking a question. Go straight to the point :-)

Comment: Yes; it isn't particularly easy, but neither is it particularly hard.  What did you try?  How would you describe the manual process?  How are the numbers stored (array, or separate variables)?  Can you modify the variables, or must they stay unchanged?  Do you need 3 or 4?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an overly clever trick to get the second largest number with ternary operators. But you can make use of the ternary operation for getting the smallest number:

```
int min(int a, int b) {
    return (a < b)? a : b;
}


int secondLargest(int a, int b, int c) {
    return (a < b && a < c)? min(b, c) : 
           (b < a && b < c)? min(a, c) :
                             min(a, b);
}
```

For 4 numbers we can make use of the previously defined functions:

```
int secondLargest(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    int minVar = (min(a, b), min(c, d))
    return a == minVar? secondLargest(b, c, d) :
           b == minVar? secondLargest(a, c, d) :
           c == minVar? secondLargest(a, b, d) :
                        secondLargest(a, b, c) :
}
```

You can keep this up for arbitrarily large numbers of variables but at some point it just makes more sense to sort them in an array and then read out the next-to-last entry.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the second largest of 3 numbers (`a`,`b` and `c`) using the ternary operator as follows:

```
int x = (a >= b && a >= c) ? ((b >= c) ? b : c) : 
    ((b >= c) ? ((a >= c) ? a : c) : ((a >= b) ? a : b));
```

The idea is to find which is the largest, then pick the largest of the other two -- the largest value other than the largest of all three.

In the above, `(a >= b && a >= c)` will be *true* if a is the largest (larger than `b` and `c`)... If it is, the result is `((b >= c) ? b : c)`, which gives the larger of `b` and `c`.

If `a` was *not* the largest, we evaluate `((b >= c) ? ((a >= c) ? a : c) : ((a >= b) ? a : b))`.  In that, `(b >= c)` checks whether `b` is the largest of the three (we already know `a` isn't, so we just compare `b` and `c`)... and if `b` is the largest of the three, we use `((a >= c) ? a : c)` to get the largest of `a` and `c`.

If neither `a` nor `b` is the largest, then `c` must be... so we evaluate `((a >= b) ? a : b)` to get the largest of `a` and `b`.

The same pattern can be extended to four numbers instead of three... but even with three it's getting quite long, and it would probably make more sense to use a (possibly inline) function with a more straightforward method instead.